# Include signature for new messages only. Evolution mail client

Tags: thunderbird, email, evolution, signature

Previously I found on Thunderbird, there's a option called

checkbox: Include signature for replies.

If I un-select this box, Thunderbird adding signature only for the new messages. Not for replies.

I need the exact same behavior on Evolution also.
Is there any similar option on Evolution mail? 
Because I don't want all the replies dispatch with the signature. Currently I always have to manually remove my signature when replying.

Comment: I'm also curious about this setting, and I haven't found anything yet. Have you found a solution to this?